# How to use trigger to track number from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

What I have done so far

```
create or replace trigger trigger_position
before insert or update of education
on JobApplication
for each row

begin

update education_tracker 
set total_application = total_application + 1
where JobApplication.education =  education_tracker.education_level;
end;
```

tables:

```
create table education_tracker( 
education_level varchar2(20), 
total_application number
);


create table JobApplication(
job_id number,
applicant_name varchar2(100),
address varchar2(120),
postcode varchar2(8),
email varchar2(30),
mobile varchar2(11),
marital varchar2(20),
education varchar2(20),
position varchar2(100)
);
```

I think the problem is in the where statement but i am not sure exactly what is the issue

Comment: In addition to the technical answers to the immediate question, I would advise against even attempting to do this - attempting to constantly update a counter that can/should be calculated at query time by simply selecting against the base data.  It's not a matter of 'if' the stored calculation is out of synch with the base data, but 'when'.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is wrong with defining `total_application` as computed column in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `NEW` table:

```
create or replace trigger trigger_position
before insert or update of education
on JobApplication
for each row

begin

update education_tracker 
set total_application = total_application + 1
where :NEW.education =  education_tracker.education_level;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a trigger normally refers to `:NEW` or `:OLD`.  In your case, you seem to want:

```
update education_tracker et
    set total_application = total_application + 1
    where et.education_level = :NEW.education;
```

Notes:

- This assumes that the value  of `total_application` is initialized or defaulted to `0` (or at least not to `NULL`.
- For an `update` this does not subtract 1 from the previous total for the old value.  Your code doesn't do that, but it looks like a bug.
- Similarly, this trigger doesn't handle `delete`, where (presumably) you would want to adjust the value as well.